# Can't get tagging to work with cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

Tags: cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I am currently having issues with using tagging with the `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` package. I know that the `cypress-tags` has been removed and made redundant so I'm trying to set up tagging using the new syntax but to no avail.

Here is my feature:

```html
Feature: duckduckgo.com
    Rule: I am on a desktop
        Scenario: visiting the frontpage
            When I visit <site>
            Then I should see a search bar

            @google
            Examples:
                | site              |
                | google.com        |
            
            @duckduckgo
            Examples:
                | site              |   
                | duckduckgo.com    |
```

And my step definitions:

```html
import { When, Then } from "@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor";

When(`I visit` + url, () => {
  if(url === 'duckduckgo.com') return cy.visit("https://www.duckduckgo.com");
  if(url === 'google.com') return cy.visit("https://www.google.com");
});

Then("I should see a search bar", () => {
  cy.get("input").should(
    "have.attr",
    "placeholder",
    "Search the web without being tracked"
  );
});
```

When I try to run my tests with `npx cypress run --env tags="@google"`, it gives me an error saying `url` in my steps definitions isn't defined. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add script with this command in package.json file this way:

```
"scripts": {
    "open:test": "npm run clean:report && cypress open --env configFile=test,TAGS=@test" (or any tag you need)
}
```

And then use it as:

```
npn run open:test
```

The main difference besides rapping it into script is not using quotes, maybe this will help you